# Deploying Ghost - How to define the root path of an application that is managed with NPM forever?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, ghost-blog

I installed [Ghost Blog](https://ghost.org/) with a subdomain (http://blog.example.com) on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS behind Apache 2.4.7 as a Proxy.

Ghost is located in `var/www/html/ghost` and can be started temporarily with `sudo npm start`, which works fine.

However, when I want to permanently deploy Ghost using [NPM forever](https://www.npmjs.org/package/forever), which I installed globally following the [official Ghost guide](http://docs.ghost.org/installation/deploy/), I get the following error message:

`info:    Forever processing file: index.js
error:   Cannot start forever
error:   script /home/myuser/index.js does not exist.`

Simply copying `index.js` to the predefined npm forever root location does not solve the problem, as the Ghost application is not located there. I also tried `sudo NODE_ENV=production forever start var/www/html/ghost/index.js` without success.

I always get a 503 Error - Service Unavailable.

How do I tell NPM forever to look for the file in `var/www/html/ghost/index.js`?

Comment: If you're on linux, it's `/var/`, not `var/`. Why not just open the terminal in the folder which contains `index.js` and just run `forever start index.js`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are not giving forever the correct file. That is what this error is saying (error:   script /home/myuser/index.js does not exist.). There is no index.js in your /home/myuser directory.

So, to start Ghost with forever first cd to the ghost directory:

`cd /var/www/html/ghost`

and then do the forever start:

`sudo NODE_ENV=production forever start index.js`

Should be good to go once you do that

Comment: I finally got it running by uninstalling and reinstalling NPM Forever and running it with `sudo forever start index.js` in the ghost folder. Everything else strangely does not work.